# How to split pandas dataframe columns that contain lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I'm trying to split a two types of pandas dataframe that contains a column with lists inner.

**type 1**

```
col1 col2
------------
foo [foo,hi]
doo [li,ha]
```

**type 2**

```
col1
---------------
[foo, [foo,hi]]
[doo [li,ha]]
```

Is there a way to split both dataframe in columns and get

```
col1 col2 col3
--------------
foo, foo, hi
doo, li, ha
```

Thanks

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([flatten(x) for x in df.to_numpy().tolist()])`. The function in that link is flexible enough to work for both.

Comment: thanks. but it's giving me an error: `NameError: name 'flatten' is not defined`

Comment: thanks! it works perfect! @ALollz please propose your answer.

Comment: since the majority of the question can be answered in that other post, I think it should remain a duplicate. Still it is a good question, so I would not delete, as it can direct other people with similar problems to one area with suitable answers.